# Unable to navigate Amazon pagination with Python and BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to create a simple web scraper program to scrape the book titles of a 100 bestseller list on Amazon. I've used this code before on another site with no problems. But for some reason, it scraps the first page fine but then posts the same results for the following iterations.

I'm not sure if it's something to do with how Amazon creates its urls or not. When I manually enter the "#2" (and beyond) at the end of the url in the browser it navigates fine.

*(Once the scrape is working I plan on dumping the data in csv files. But for now, print to the terminal will do.)*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(5):
    url = "https://smile.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-Dystopian-Science-Fiction/zgbs/digital-text/6361470011/ref=zg_bs_nav_kstore_4_158591011#{}".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    for book in soup.find_all('div', class_='zg_itemWrapper'):
        title = book.find('div', class_='p13n-sc-truncate')
        name = book.find('a', class_='a-link-child')
        price = book.find('span', class_='p13n-sc-price')

        print(title)
        print(name)
        print(price)

print("END")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem that you have to face, some sites load the data asynchronous(with ajax) those are XMLHttpRequest that you can see in the tab networking of your DOM inspector. Usually the websites load the data from a different endpoint with `POST` method to solve that you can use urllib or requests library.

In this case the request is through a GET method and you can scrape it from this url with no need of extend your code https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-Dystopian-Science-Fiction/zgbs/digital-text/6361470011/ref=zg_bs_pg_3?_encoding=UTF8&pg=3&ajax=1 where you only change the `pg` parameter